# Laravel query builder mass update - sum current value + another value

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-query-builder

I am aware that we can do mass updates with Laravel query builder with it's `update()` method:

```
DB::table('my_table')
    ->where('created_at', '>=', '2000-01-01')
    ->update(['column' => 10]);
```

This would be equivalent to this query:

```
UPDATE my_table SET column = 10 WHERE created_at >= '2000-01-01'
```

What if I wanted to increment that column value by ten, instead of setting a fixed value?

This is what I mean, in SQL:

```
UPDATE my_table SET column = column + 10 WHERE created_at >= '2000-01-01'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply use `Db::raw` method:

```
DB::table('my_table'
  ->where('created_at', '>=', '2000-01-01')
  ->update([
    'column'=> DB::raw('column+10'), 
  ]);
```

More informations: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/queries#raw-expressions

Other solution, use the increment method (https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/queries#increment-and-decrement):

```
DB::table('my_table')
   ->where('created_at', '>=', '2000-01-01')
   ->increment('column', 10);
```

Comment: I was not aware of increment/decrement. Thanks